# Qpython 3 if/elif/else

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por que mey QPython Android não aceita uma condição simples de if/elif/else?
Estou usando Python 3.

```
x = input('Select an option... ')
if x == 1:
    print('xxxx')
elif x == 2:
    print('yyyy')
elif x == 3:
    print('zzzz')
else:
    print('lalalalala')
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlS40.jpg)

Eu tenho certeza de que tudo está indentado corretamente, mais ainda assim ele sempre me dá o primeiro `elif` como erro de sintaxe, alguém sabe porquê?

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]! Retirei a parte em inglês porque este site é somente em português. E usando o código que está na pergunta, não ocorre o erro de sintaxe, então deve ser algum outro detalhe em outra parte do código...

Answer (score 1):

A função [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) retorna uma string, e nos `if`'s você está comparando com números. Então você pode escolher se faz a comparação com strings (colocando os números entre aspas):

```
x = input('Select an option... ')
if x == '1':
    print('xxxx')
elif x == '2':
    print('yyyy')
elif x == '3':
    print('zzzz')
else:
    print('lalalalala')
```

Ou se transforma o resultado de `input` em um número, usando [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
x = int(input('Select an option... '))
if x == 1:
    print('xxxx')
elif x == 2:
    print('yyyy')
elif x == 3:
    print('zzzz')
else:
    print('lalalalala')
```

Lembrando que `int` pode lançar um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) se você não digitar um número. Então você pode usar um `while` que, enquanto não for digitado um número, continua pedindo que o usuário digite novamente:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('Select an option... '))
        break # número digitado, pode sair do while
    except ValueError:
        print('Você não digitou um número, tente novamente')

if x == 1:
    print('xxxx')
elif x == 2:
    print('yyyy')
elif x == 3:
    print('zzzz')
else:
    print('lalalalala')
```

Comment: Boa noite hkotsubo. Agradeço as boas-vindas e a atenção. Tentei sua sugestão e esse não parece ser o problema.  Tentei à exaustão encontrar qualquer outro erro, mas o aplicativo sempre indica a mesma linha do elif como fonte do problema. Estou aprendendo, mas já fiz um código similar no computador e ele funcionou sem problemas. O Qpython 3 pra android foi o primeiro a dar problema. A propósito, se não se importa, como formatou o código para aparecer "inteligível" dessa maneira?

Comment: @Lehetex Para formatar o código aqui no site, siga [estas dicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Quanto ao erro de sintaxe, com o código que vc passou ele não acontece comigo. Se funcionou em outro editor, talvez o problema seja alguma coisa no Qpython, não sei. Pode ser tabs e espaços misturados ou algum outro detalhe...